# Elasticsearch index mapping not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm new to elasticsearch, and have tried reading all the docs I can find, but I'm struggling to understand the mapping behaviour of index creation.

I have AWS CloudWatch importing logs from my application into ES via a Lambda subscription.

I am using the Dev Tools UI in Kibana (on AWS) to talk to ES.  Running the following PUT command lets me set up a new index.  However the documents that are created do not have any of the fields which I have set up in my mapping.

```
PUT cwl-2018.08.09
{
  "settings" : {
      "index" : {
          "number_of_shards" : 1
      }
  },
  "mappings": {    
    "test-log-group": {     
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "level": { "type": "text" },
        "message": { "type": "text" },      
        "logger": { "type": "text" },
        "url": { "type": "text" }      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is an example document sent to ES via CloudWatch

```
{
    "_index": "cwl-2018.08.09",
    "_type": "test-log-group",
    "_id": "34205467001770174210014068820960982481947713872776593408",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "time": "2018-08-09 15:49:48.1949",
      "level": "INFO",
      "message": "Test",
      "logger": "Logger",
      "applicationName": "WebSite",
      "url": "/test",
      "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36",
      "controller": "Home",
      "action": "Test",
      "@id": "34205467001770174210014068820960982481947713872776593408",
      "@timestamp": "2018-08-09T14:49:48.195Z",
      "@message": """{ "time": "2018-08-09 15:49:48.1949", "level": "INFO", "message": "Test", "logger": "Logger", "applicationName": "WebSite", "url": "\/test", "userAgent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/68.0.3440.84 Safari\/537.36", "controller": "Home", "action": "Test" }""",
      "@owner": "751777751431",
      "@log_group": "test-log-group",
      "@log_stream": "2018/08/09T15.12.19 - 5bb0c1a1-9405-4fc3-98ec-f8c98553f4a8"
    }
  }
```

I would expect to see fields called 'level', 'message', 'logger' and 'url' in the document, outside of the '_source' field.

Is my mapping wrong?
Am I misunderstanding what I should be able to create in terms of the document structure?

Comment: Anything you send to ES will land **inside** the `_source` field.

Comment: Thank you.  What is the point of the mapping then?  If I just let ES create it's auto-mapping then I still get the same _source field populated with everything sent to ES.  Isn't the point of the mapping to let me discard the stuff I don't care about, and also to allow more controlled searching of the fields by better defining their data types?

Comment: It allows *you* to dictate how ES indexes your documents rather than relying on its defaults. For example, you can explicitly indicate which fields contain GPS coordinates rather than letting it guess. You can explicitly specify (non-ISO 8601default) date formats. And more.

Comment: The point of the mapping is to make sure that the fields get the type you want them to. If you need to discard fields you need to either use an ingest pipeline with a [remove processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/remove-processor.html) or prune the unwanted fields in your Lambda. You can also set  [`dynamic` to `false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#dynamic-field-mapping) if you don't want your mapping to be updated with new fields (i.e. keep it nice and clean), but that won't modify your source.

Comment: Thanks both.  Perhaps I need to clarify my question with an example.  If I want to analyse the data in Kibana, say graphing the number of ERROR level logs per hour, isn't that why I want to create a well defined document of type "test-log-group", with a top-level property called "level"?  That would allow more efficient analysis than having to parse the "_source" field of each document to extract the level value.   Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the whole point!

Comment: The purpose of the mapping is to tell Elasticsearch how to convert (map) the fields of your document into its own weird internal form in way that allows the document to be found via a search. The data that Elasticsearch actually indexes for a field might be, e.g., converted to lowercase and stripped of stopwords and have every token truncated at the sixth character.  Another to think of it: the criteria by which you might want to *search* for a document might be different than the exact contents of that document. It can be counter-intuitive, to be sure.